# For loop doesen't work in custom function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a problem that I simply can't figure out.
I have an app, where I use pop to animate it, and an array of images I want to loop through, when the animation is finished.

```
let images: [AnyObject] = [UIImage(named: "cat1")!, UIImage(named: "cat2")!, UIImage(named: "cat3")!, UIImage(named: "cat4")!]
```

Animation finish:

```
func pop_animationDidStop(anim: POPAnimation!, finished: Bool) {
    if finished {
        if (anim.name == "myanim") {
            self.showImages()
        }
    }
}
```

Imageloop:

```
func showImages() {

    print("This Prints")
    for img in self.images as! [UIImage]{
        print(img)
        print("But this fails")
    }                
}
```

Odd thing is, that if I copy that same function into the .viewDidLoad(), it works fine, and prints all the images. I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong. Before I discovered that it works find in .viewDidLoad(), I tried changing the types of the array, and multiple other types, in the for loop, but now that it works one place, and not another, I'm clueless.

This works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    for img in self.images as! [UIImage]{
        print(img)
        print("This prints all the images")
    }  
}
```

All xcode returns as error is "(lldb)", and that does not help me a lot.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the images array is populated at the time of the `showImages()` call? Can you verify in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, as it prints the first one, and then not the others. Also, I've tried putting the array directly in the showImages() function, to make sure it was populated pre-loop

Answer (score 0):

Minutes after posting this, and several hours of wondering and rubbing my head, I tried something random and placed the function showImages() above .viewDidLoad(). This fixed it, I had no idea that had any matter in calling functions.

Comment: It doesn't, that likely wasn't what "fixed" it

Comment: Exactly my thought, but nothing else what changed.